# Script in webpart freeze the whole site

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online

I have a JavaScript in my script editor that on page load freezes the browser . I can't use SharePoint designer to remove it because the script is in a script editor. I have tried disabling JavaScript in browser but then I can't access the edit mode on page. Is there any solutions to remove the script?

Comment: I managed to fix it with removing the code in my home.aspx with Sharepoint designer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add `"?contents=1"` to the url of the page. There you can delete not working webparts and also closed webparts from the page. For example:

```
 http://mywebsite/default.aspx?contents=1
```